# How to ignore values that are divided by zero

Tags: python

My values can't be divided by zero. However, I would still like to run the other values. Is there a solution to this? I have done some research and I know that people uses np.errstate and np.where, but I am not sure how to apply that to my code.

```
diesel_electric = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,17,23,22,22,21]
electric = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,0,1,1,12,314,560]
year = [2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018]

fuels = input('Please select a fuel type: ')
if fuels in ['1']:
    for i in range(len(electric)):
        per = (electric[i]-electric[i-1])/electric[i-1]*100
        if per>= 6:
            print(f"{year[i]} {electric[i]}")
                 
elif fuels in ['2']:
    for i in range(len(diesel_electric)):
        per = (diesel_electric[i]-diesel_electric[i-1])/diesel_electric[i-1]*100
        if per>= 6:
            print(f"{year[i]} {diesel_electric[i]}")
```

Comment: You could check if they are zero before you divide by them.

Comment: Couldn't you just do a simple `if variable_name > 0` then the code to process the variable beneath?

Comment: Can't divide by zero is one of the first rule you learn in Computer Science Degree at University. Did you do a bootcamp or the University ? The other replies are good.

Answer (score 2):

Either you can apply a "if" condition to remove all zero values from processing. or you can take your code and insert it in a try and except block. that will not return any error for dividing by zero.

```
try:
    print 1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print "You can't divide by zero!"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [try/except statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) with the [ZeroDivisionError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ZeroDivisionError):

```
try:
    # some calculation
    1 / 0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in the `diesel_electric` list, so you can just check if it is zero before doing the computation:

```
for i in range(len(diesel_electric)):
    if diesel_electric[i-1] != 0:
        per = (diesel_electric[i]-diesel_electric[i-1])/diesel_electric[i-1]*100
        if per>= 6:
            print(f"{year[i]} {diesel_electric[i]}")
    else:
        continue
```

It seems, though, that you'll find an aerror anyway because when `i==0`, then `i-1 = -1`, which isn't a valid index. So I'd say you start the loop from `i = 1` in both loops:

```
for i in range(1,len(diesel_electric)):
    if diesel_electric[i-1] != 0:
        per = (diesel_electric[i]-diesel_electric[i-1])/diesel_electric[i-1]*100
        if per>= 6:
            print(f"{year[i]} {diesel_electric[i]}")
    else:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `try:`  and `except:`  to ignore or catch errors such as these, or just make some if and else statments to trace division by zero and skipping it

here is an example with `try:`

```py
diesel_electric = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,17,23,22,22,21]
electric = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,0,1,1,12,314,560]
year = [2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018]

fuels = input('Please select a fuel type: ')
if fuels in ['1']:
    for i in range(len(electric)):
        try:
            per = (electric[i]-electric[i-1])/electric[i-1]*100
            if per>= 6:
                print(f"{year[i]} {electric[i]}")
        except:
            pass
                 
elif fuels in ['2']:
    for i in range(len(diesel_electric)):
        try:
            per = (diesel_electric[i]-diesel_electric[i-1])/diesel_electric[i-1]*100
            if per>= 6:
                print(f"{year[i]} {diesel_electric[i]}")
        except:
            pass
```

[image: running in IDLE]

Comment: It is a better python practice to specify what kind of errors in the except block. Otherwise, bugs might not be catched.